# Eclipse Angular2 plugin not working correctly

Tags: angular, eclipse-plugin

I have installed Angular2 eclipse plugin. But when I want to create new angular2 project I can`t find it in projects list.

[image]

**Plugin details:**

[image]

Comment: plz let me know that which plugin your using, this one https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse#group-details

Comment: yes, this one.  Plugin version 1.2 .

Comment: are you using Eclipse Versions: Neon (4.6)?

Comment: You have installed "AngularJS Eclipse" https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse which is for Angular1. You must install  "Angular2 Eclipse" https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular2-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 **Eclipse requires Eclipse JEE Neon** installation. try to make sure that your using **Eclipse requires Eclipse JEE Neon**. and update plugin to latest version it will solve your problem.